# How do I optimize the speed of my Wordpress, Elementor, and WooCommerce website on Litespeed server?

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, pagespeed-insights, litespeed

I'm trying to optimize a website ([gntac.com](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gntac.com%2F&tab=mobile)) but not sure how to proceed further. It's hosted on Litespeed server and I'm using the Litespeed Cache Plugin for Wordpress. I have enabled webp images, combined and minified javascript, minified css, and enabled quick.cloud CDN. I'm also using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) for webp replacement in css but Insights doesn't seem to recognize the change.

There are also a lot of DOM elements (presumably due to Elementor). Some of the theme elements are hidden with css on mobile. I tried to use [Mobile_Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) to only load those elements for desktop but the cache seems to be static and is either generated for mobile OR desktop but not both so the Mobile_Detect code is useless. None of this seems to have made any difference in Pagespeed Insights with tests still at around 11 for mobile and 42 for desktop.

Could anyone please provide some pointers on where to go from here? I know a little web development and SEO/optimization but this is beyond me at the moment.

Comment: If you have a large number of products or users, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256932/optimizing-custom-wordpress-sql-query-for-fetching-usermeta-data/69798009#69798009

Answer (score 0):

You can try to deactivate the cache, do the Lighthouse Check again, try to get ride of the unused script and styles and activate the cache tool again.
You should combine your css to, not only js.
The Front Page is well cached, but te product are loading up to 6 secs - which is way to long. Maybe yout server is to slow and you should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Webpage speed optimization is an art itself. On advanced levels, we look into every piece of code for optimization.

At the beginner level, I would suggest you to use Cloudflare CDN (Free Subscription) and configure Cache and Speed settings.

Second, instead of using PageSpeed Insights, use [Solarwinds Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/) to check the speed of the website.

Third, make sure that all the unnecessary plugins and themes are deleted. Clean up as much as you can. WordPress themes are the usual culprit of a slow website, use the lightest possible theme which is regularly updated and optimized.

Make sure to address Render Blocking Elements (inline critical elements or deffer) and Server Response Time (better web hosting).

Comment: We were originally using Cloudflare but the host suggested quick.cloud instead and after some quick research it looked like it was the better option for our small site. Is there a reason why you recommend Cloudflare over the other? Also, I've always liked GTMetrix but my boss wanted me to use  Insights. Why do you recommend Pingdom over these? We didn't want to put any unnecessary blame on the host but we've already discussed moving to another.

Comment: Any CDN is good as far as it serves the purpose. Cloudflare has just better compression, for small sites its free and it's easy to use. You may use GTMetrix and Insights if you are using them with plugins list Asset Cleanup Pro or any other plugin which can help you block/deffer/inline the unnecessary elements on any given page as they would tell you which resources you need to optimize. Pingdom tells you the exact loading speed of a page from the user's perspective and also recommended by many speed optimization plugins.

Comment: For a complete solution, I would suggest looking into WPMUDEV plugins and hosting. Speed won't be an issue anymore.