# Why MariaDB on my Woocommerce website consumes too much CPU?

Tags: wordpress, mariadb

I have a Woocommerce website with like 1 million product, type *simple*. (are they too many for a Woo website?)

Code and database are on same server

**Server:** *16 cores* and *62 GB RAM*.

**MariaDB:** *mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2*

Sometimes the CPU gets full and website becomes unresponsive.

I can see via `htop` MariaDB taking all of CPU.
[image]

It has CLoudflare installed.

Access logs shows traffic to `/wp-json/wp/v2/product/ID-HERE` endpoints from `amazonbot`, example.

```
162.158.87.126 - - [03/Feb/2024:15:52:35 +0100] "GET /wp-json/wp/v2/product_tag/766 HTTP/2.0" 504 164 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5 (Amazonbot/0.1; +https://developer.amazon.com/support/amazonbot)" "3.224.220.101,3.224.220.101"
```

Does that make sense? or should I disable Woo API at all because I dont use it for any purpose.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows these kind of queries hung for over 2000 seconds

```
SELECT
    post_modified_gmt 
FROM
    wp_posts 
WHERE
    post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post_type IN ( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'e-landing-page', 'elementor_library', 'product' ) 
ORDER BY
    post_modified_gmt DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT
    wp_posts.ID 
FROM
    wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
WHERE
    1 = 1 
    AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5 ) ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
    AND ((
            wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
        )) 
GROUP BY
    wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY
    wp_posts.post_date DESC 
    LIMIT 0,
    1
```

I have following INDEXes

wp_posts

[image: wp_posts]

wp_postmeta

[image: wp_psotmeta]

wp_term_relationships

[image: wp_term_relationships]

### EDIT in response to Wilson

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;`

   +----------+
   | COUNT(*) |
   +----------+
   |      602 |
   +----------+
   1 row in set (0.004 sec)
2. `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` https://pastebin.com/UnCJ3Hr3
3. `STATUS;` https://pastebin.com/2JMRL51B
4. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` https://pastebin.com/Ze69SqLw
5. `top -b -n 1` https://pastebin.com/EqFuchH4
6. `top -b -n 1 -H` https://pastebin.com/aqx8rrvs
7. `ulimit -a` https://pastebin.com/T0HT5Afh
8. `iostat -xm 5 3` https://pastebin.com/nE3AwTvQ
9. `df -`h https://pastebin.com/1grfXYMd
10. `df -i` https://pastebin.com/1wnUJxpY
11. `free -h` https://pastebin.com/ND3E4iR8
12. `cat /proc/meminfo` https://pastebin.com/ehGtav7F
13. `lsb_release -a` https://pastebin.com/RZj2FFFz
14. `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` https://justpaste.it/baovl
15. `lsblk` https://pastebin.com/i9sLVur2
16. `SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 100000;` https://pastebin.com/RYs0u9dj
17. Storage media is SSD
18. `wp-config.php` https://pastebin.com/fnZ88uui
19. `findfragtables.sql` output settings https://pastebin.com/UzwzTjvi

Everything is provided except htop as its already in screenshot above.
PS: during the all things I provided, the CPU never exceeded 80%, and average load was around 60%

### Edit 2:

I forgot to write that the CPU goes 100% when I try to do INSERTs in the `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables, the INSERTs happen instantly but after that, CPU goes insane, probably MySQL starts doing re-indexing behind-the-scenes?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I added all information. Please check

Comment: Umair-Ayub   Storage media is HDD, SSD or NVME?  Analysis in process.  Thanks for posting data.

Comment: I would think any API that is NOT used should not be enabled.  No need to introduce clutter that will never be used.

Comment: Umair-Ayub  Please post TEXT results of this query, when you have a minute.  

    SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 100000;

Comment: Thank you for the SUM query of table space occupied.  Your workload analysis will be completed today.  Answer with suggestions should be posted within a couple of hours.

Comment: Your ratio of free_space to data_space at about 10% is very reasonable.  If you would like our query to findfragtables.sql provide an email address, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck mani619cash@gmail.com

Comment: Our findfragtables.sql - should be in your email inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the first query as

```
SELECT  MAX(post_modified_gmt)
    FROM  wp_posts
    WHERE  post_status = 'publish'
      AND  post_type IN ( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'e-landing-page',
                          'elementor_library', 'product' );
```

and have this "covering" index:

```
INDEX(post_status,        -- first because of '='
      post_type,          -- next,
      post_modified_gmt)  -- to make it "covering"
```

You are using 10.5.  The "191 kludge" is no longer needed as of  MariaDB 10.2.2 (MySQL 5.7.7).  Removing that "prefixing" from serveral of the indexes it will help many queries.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your OS adjustment and my.cnf [mysqld] section

Your ulimit -a report indicates Open Files limit is 1024.
From your OS Command Prompt,

```
ulimit -n 64000 and press Enter to change this dynamic variable.  No restart required. 
to make this persistent, here is link to an overview. 

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/  

Do not set to 500000 as the overview suggests, use 64000 and MySQL will be able to open_files_limit of 32,768 to avoid open starvation that exists today. Expect opened_tables RPS of 934 to come down significantly.
```

my.cnf [mysqld] suggestions,

```
read_buffer_size=1M  # from 8M to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 178,608
read_rnd_buffer_size=16K  # from 4M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 163,840 
innodb_old_blocks_pct=1  # from 37 percent of innodb_buffer_pool_size reserved
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4  #  from 1 to reduce mutex contention
innodb_buffer_pool_size=38G  # from 5G to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads RPS of 59,698
```

There are many more performance improving opportunities.  Please view profile.

Comment: Can you give us clue on your server's old/new time to complete your slow query(queries)? With the query source for 2 queries, please.

Comment: I forgot to write that the CPU goes 100% when I try to do INSERTs in the `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables, the INSERTs happen instantly but after that, CPU goes insane, probably MySQL starts doing re-indexing behind-the-scenes?

Comment: @UmairAyub     Could you post your WP reindex settings information.  Also CPU at 100% is effectively about 8% busy when you have 12 CPU's as documented in your htop display.   CPU % / Cores = average busy %

Comment: @UmairAyub      Have you looked at and applied the plugin for WordPress improvements?  
https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/  
   Most of the development has been by Rick James, Oliver Jones and others credited with this plugin for WordPress speed improvements.  Be sure to scan down to find WP_CLI section if you have tables of significant size to minimize/avoid timeouts.

Comment: @UmairAyub     One more foundational document before you leap into the WordPress plug-in.  Please read though it twice.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256932/optimizing-custom-wordpress-sql-query-for-fetching-usermeta-data/69798009#69798009

Comment: @UmairAyub  Please post your wp-config.php file.  Will double check debug situation.

Comment: "post your WP reindex settings information" - How can I check?
"Have you looked at and applied the plugin for WordPress improvements?" - Not yet, I will do it today.
"Please post your wp-config.php file" - Added in OP.

Comment: @UmairAyub  This URL may help you find your table reindex settings.  https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=41&q=how+do+I+get+to+wordpress+reindex+data+table+frequency+settings

Comment: `findfragtables.sql` output settings https://pastebin.com/UzwzTjvi

Comment: we did yours my.cnf [mysqld] suggestions and everything working smoothly since then. CPU doesnt go up when we do INSERTs.

Comment: @UmairAyub Wonderful.  Consider scrolling down to 'Write a review' for us at this URL - https://mysqlservertuning.com/collections/shop-our-services/products/my-top-4-global-variable-suggestions    Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Have you OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl_name;  for the first 25 tables listed in the findfragtables.sql output?  The rest are so small they will have little impact.

Comment: Not yet, if I do it, will it take affect my website? because its a live woocommerce website with people ordering almost all the times.

Comment: @UmairAyub     Could we use Skype to chat?  My Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com.  We are in GMT -5 hrs.